# string.Format when the format is a variable

Tags: c#, formatting

I want to be able to change the formatting of a string according to a format which is stored in a variable:

```
DateTime dd = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-6-1");
string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"),$"{dd:D}").Dump();
string foo = "D";
string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"), $"{dd}:{foo}").Dump();
```

In the example above, at line #4, I want to be able to print the date with a formatting which is dynamic - the formatting is stored as a variable.

Currently, the output of line #2 is "Friday, 1 June 2018", as expected, and the output of line #4 is: "01/06/2018 0:00:00:D"

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that isn't solved by using `dd.ToString(format, provider)`?

Comment: @john you are absolutely right. If you want to post as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: Would `$"{dd:{foo}}"` work? Just curious

Comment: @Rafalon won't compile

Comment: `dd.ToString(foo, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")).Dump();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:

```
string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"), $"{{0:{foo}}}", dd)
```

The interpolated string evaluates to `"{0:D}"`, note how the double brackets are used to escape a single bracket in a `$""` string.

Answer (score 1):

Your current method is incorrect. The signature of `string.Format` is as follows:

```
Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object)
```

As it stands, you're hitting this one instead:

```
Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object[])
```

Why? Because you're using interpolated strings (`$""`). The formatting is actually taking place within the interpolated string, not within the `Format(...)`, so the culture information is being lost as the interpolated string is just being passed onwards.

There are two solutions to this:

1. Use `Format` correctly:

   `string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"), $"{{0:{foo}}}", dd).Dump();`

   This will evaluate the format to "{0:D}", and then apply it (with the culture) to dd to produce the result.
2. Use `ToString` on the date object:

   `dd.ToString(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"), foo).Dump();`

Comment: Are you sure the first solution works? I got a `FormatException`.

Comment: @john, the 2nd statement works, thanks for that, but unfortunately I need it to work on a string and not on an object (the DateTime example was just one case)